# How to retrieve the value of the select tag in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, struts2, struts-tags

I'm using Struts `<s:select>` tag to retrieve value from my database in displayed in the form on JSP page I stored the value in list object using following code

```java
ps = con.prepareStatement("select emp_ty_name, em_ty_id  from emptype");
set = ps.executeQuery();
while (set.next()) {
    typeID.add(set.getInt("em_ty_id"));             
    typeName.add(set.getString("emp_ty_name"));
}
```

and in JSP page I display the name correctly but in place of the value it's showing 0 (zero)
value

```xml
<s:select label="Employee Type" list="typeName" name="empType_em_ty_id" />
```

Comment: Could you show me where do you see a value place?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a List of an object with two properties, instead of two separate lists.

Then create an object like

```
public class EmpType { 
    private Integer typeID;
    private String  typeName;
    // getters and setters 
}
```

in your action declare a list of it, then populate it:

```
private List<EmpType> empTypes = new ArrayList<EmpType>();
// getters and setters 

public String execute(){
    // stuff...

    while (set.next()) {
        EmpType et = new EmpType();
        et.setTypeID(set.getInt("em_ty_id"));
        et.setTypeName(set.getString("emp_ty_name"));
        empTypes.add(et);
    }

    // stuff 

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

iterate your objects and specify key and value with `listKey` and `listValue` attributes:

```
<s:select label = "Employee Type" 
           list = "empTypes" 
        listKey = "typeID"
      listValue = "typeName"
           name = "empType_em_ty_id" />
```

Comment: mmtrue, skimmed over that. Let's take a step back then.

Comment: still doesn't answer why the value is empty (showing 0).

Comment: The way is right, but answer is incomplete, so less useful. I will upvote if the answer will be completed. (I don't expect it though)

Comment: They should be equals, I've no clue on why he got 0 (in key or value, it is not even clear that). Feel free to answer with the explanation to that if you got it, I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

In place of the value (I think it's a field value of the `select` tag, i.e. the question that you didn't clarify) you have a value of the property which is a primitive type `int` or `long`, that is not initialized, hence contains `0` value. In Struts you map JSP fields by name, and if you didn't specify a `value` attribute to preselect a *default* value, then the value will be retrieved by `name` attribute. The value of the `name` attribute is an OGNL expression `empType_em_ty_id` that is evaluated in the value stack, and returns a property value. This value is not showing to you, but set when you `change` the value of the `option` and retrieved when you `submit` the form. Usually for the `select` tag required two action properties: one for the value, and other for the options list. For example

```
private Integer empType_em_ty_id;
private Map<Integer,String> typeMap = new HashMap<>();
//getters and setters

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
  ...
  PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select emp_ty_name, em_ty_id  from emptype");
  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()) {
    typeMap.put(
     rs.getInt("em_ty_id"), 
     rs.getString("emp_ty_name")
    );
  }
  //initializing value 
  empType_em_ty_id = typeMap.keySet().iterator().next();
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

the JSP

```
<s:select label="Employee Type" list="typeMap" name="empType_em_ty_id" />
```

About the selected value: it is used to save the object property which value is selected from the list of another objects. The key of the selected object should be a foreign key of the object which value is selected. In my example I've just taken a value from the same collection, but not from the another object for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: thanx thnx guys my problem is solved now i got clear picture now

Comment: @user3218220 If your problem is solved then you could accept (green mark on the left) the answer which mostly helped you to solve your problem.